How to maintain logout audit trail in spring boot microservices when user close the browser without explicitly logging out?
The challenges arise when user :
1.Close the browser directly without logging out
2. does not perform any action the triggers a logout api call,leaving their JWT token active until it expires.
Without relying on before unload event in javascript
I have done for login .but for logout this question arise.I am having jwt but this won't give me proper exact time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can try Beacon API to trigger the API for the audit log. From MDN:

The Beacon API is used to send an asynchronous and non-blocking request to a web server. The request does not expect a response. Unlike requests made using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch API, the browser guarantees to initiate beacon requests before the page is unloaded and to run them to completion.

Reference Stackblitz
